# Select maximum value and corresponding value in another field using Postgres 8.3 or lower

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

So I have to do the above and I am using Postgres 8.3 so I cannot use window functions. 
I cannot use the LIMIT function (this is a homework question).

I have a query like this (I omitted the desc conditions):

```
SELECT MAX(count)
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM memberlist
  WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
  GROUP BY id
) AS STT
```

Memberlist contains members who each have a desc and a job.
Members can have multiple jobs. So the above query counts each member to see how many jobs they have (as each member has their own id).

Now, my issue is the above query works fine for getting just the maximu number of jobs 1 person has but as soon I try to get the corresponding name for that 1 person I run into issues.

```
SELECT mi.name, MAX(count)
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM memberlist
  WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
  GROUP BY id
) STT JOIN memberinfo mi ON (stt.id = mi.id)
GROUP BY mi.name;
```

The above gives me all the names for everybody (I think) and not just those with the maximum number of jobs (which should be 3 members who each have 25 jobs). I used the id from memberlist and joined it with memberinfo to get the name in memberinfo.

So how can I could get the name of each person who has the max number of jobs so I have 3 rows of two columns (Name, Num jobs) as my solution?

I did make an alternative query which is ugly but works.
Here it is:

```
SELECT mi.name, stt.count
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM memberlist 
    WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
    GROUP BY id
) stt
JOIN memberinfo mi ON (mi.id = stt.id)
WHERE stt.count = 
(
  SELECT MAX(count)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM memberlist 
    WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
    GROUP BY id
  ) AS MAXSTT
)
```

I thought this solution was not a very good one and inefficient so I am looking to improving it or using another approach.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Unfortunately we do have a execution time limit which is my issue.

Comment: As it turns out, this solution is efficient enough. However, is there a better way to do it, id still like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your inner query to join `memberlist` so you can retrieve the columns you want. Then you can limit your query to those with the maximum count via `having count(*) = (subquery)`

```
SELECT m.id, mi.name, count(*) as count 
FROM memberlist m
JOIN memberinfo mi ON m.id = mi.id
WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
GROUP BY m.id, mi.name
HAVING count(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(count)
    FROM (
        SELECT id, count(*) as count 
        FROM memberlist 
        WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
        GROUP BY id
    ) AS MAXSTT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using EXIST might be improvement. I think that your query should look like that:

```
SELECT mi.name, stt.count
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM memberlist 
    WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
    GROUP BY id
) stt
JOIN memberinfo mi ON (mi.id = stt.id)
WHERE exists 
(
  SELECT MAX(count)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM memberlist 
    WHERE desc = ...some conditions...
    GROUP BY id
  ) AS MAXSTT
  having MAX(MAXSTT.count)=stt.count
)
```